# REST API, data returning way for success and error

Tags: php, json, web-services, api, rest

i am writing a REST API and would like to know weather this is a good practice or not.

Below are sample JSON response.

Error response,

```
{
  "code": 1100,
  "status": false,
  "message": "Values of imei/email/pin cannot be empty.",
  "server_time": "2013-11-28 09:13:06"
}
```

Success Response, without some data

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "id": "2",
    "isNewParent": false,
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "dob": null,
    "gender": null,
    "username": null
  },
  "server_time": "2013-11-28 09:07:23"
}
```

Success response, with data

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "id": "3",
    "isNewParent": true,
    "firstName": "Saman",
    "lastName": "kalhara",
    "dob": 2002-10-29,
    "gender": 0,
    "username": 'saman88'
  },
  "server_time": "2013-11-28 10:07:23"
}
```

The question is, about the success response without data, some mobile developers are requesting the json response to contain with tags only for the ones with values and to skip the null values.  so it would look like,

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "id": "2",
    "isNewParent": false,
  },
  "server_time": "2013-11-28 09:07:23"
}
```

I am in a dilemma on what to do. i prefer the way its done and would like to know if this can cause any slowness on API requests performance wise.

Comment: I would keep it like it is, in order to have always the same variables in the response. Up to the developer to test if the variable actually have a value. There's no real impact on performance given the small amount of "extra" data sent. Be careful though that your data should be in between quotes if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Thanks @Bartdude. Please check my comment on below answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't cause any slowness. If anything, you're reducing the number of key/values that have to be JSON'd. However, unless you're receiving unimaginable amounts of traffic and you don't cache, the removal of the `null` values isn't going to have any huge performance impact.

In this case, however, I'd say the best practice depends on how your dad is stored. I don't understand how something can have an ID, but no username, dob, gender, first name, or last name. Is there a reason for this?

Unless the ID has meaning, my counter to both solutions would be a response like this:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": true,
  "data": {},
  "server_time": "2013-11-28 10:07:23"
}
```

Also, if you want to strictly stick to REST, you should be using the built-in HTTP status codes and only adding additional error information if the HTTP status doesn't fully explain the response.

---

Given that a response should return data, I would say that for the sake of consistency, you should maintain a constant structure for every response that contains data. In this way, developers don't have to do excessive checks to ensure that all of the fields they need are defined before retrieving them. Determining whether a field is defined is as easy as `data['field'] === null`, so I don't understand the developer unrest. If their complaints are founded in saving bytes, unless they're making thousands of requests, having a few null values in the data object isn't going to make much of a difference at all.

Comment: Thanks for this. There is a reason to return only the id under data.  there is a situation where user(parent) will be given an option to sign in with a provided pin and email. so when the user inserts the those two and sign in, next option is update the user profile. so before updating the profile if something goes wrong in the application, it can contain only the id as verified but will require to update the profile. so "isNewParent": false. please feel free to pass your suggestions.

Comment: This doesn't sound very restful to me. RESTful APIs should be stateless (Look into the session pattern). I'll update my answer with that in mind.